# static files are not loading in my project

Tags: node.js, express

i am struggling to fix the issue that static files are not loading in my small to do app project.

`app.use('/assets', express.static('public'));`
i guess. this expression is not working.

`app.js` file.

```
var express = require('express');
var todoController = require('./controllers/todoControllers');
var app = express();

//set up template engine
app.set('view engine','ejs');

// static files
app.use('/assets', express.static('public'));

//fire to controllers

todoController(app);

//listen to port
app.listen(3000); 
console.log('you are listening to port: 3000');
```

`todo.ejs` file

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Todo List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/styles.css">
    <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/styles.css" type="text/css" />      
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My todo list</h1>
    <div id="todo-table">
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Add new item..." required />
            <button type ="submit">Add item</button>    
        </form>
        <ul>
            <% for(var i=0;i<todos.length;i++){ %>
                <li><%= todos[i].item %></li>
            <% } %>
        </ul>
    </div>
     <script src="..public/assets/todo-list.js"></script>    
   </body>
  </html>
```

when i go to localhost:3000 and inspect the page then there is an error that no css file is loaded and no js file is loaded.

Comment: you may need to join paths. Post your projects tree map. ex: 
`app.use('/assets', path.join(__dirname, '/../public'));`

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the path,

```
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

For more information please refer : https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
Also check are you trying to create virtual path.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the route `/assets` to your static middleware, and having it redirect to the public directory. But in your HTML, you're trying to access the URL `/public/assets` directly. Don't do that; just point your HREF to `/assets/styles.css` and the static middleware will properly route it over to the public directory for you.

Answer (score 0):

First require path `var path = require('path');`

Secondly if `assets` is the folder where you want to serve its content and it also live with the `app.js` file in the same folder then

`app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets')));`